# How to use a different date/time format for inputs and for human-readable text output in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

For html form date input fields, I have to use a 2019-10-27 date format. For human-readable text, I'd prefer to use one that is appropriate for the Locale, e.g. 27.10.2019 or 10/27/2019.

Spring Boot & Thymeleaf make it easy to specify `@DateTimeFormat` and automagically pick it up in `th:field` and the likes of it. Here, I specify the technical format, otherwise my forms are neither rendered nor submitted correctly.

Is there a way to make Thymeleaf or Spring use a different format for other occasions? I know I can do  `${#temporals.format(period.end, #messages.msg('formats.readable.date.month'))}`, but is there a way to somehow register that thing and make it available for automagical conversions?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `WebDataBinder`

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, final Locale locale) {
    String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    if(locale.getLanguage.equals("ar")){
        dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
}
```